# Combining query results in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection `invites` which i am using to store some invite data.Below are two rows of data i captured from my collection `invites`

```
{
        "_id" : "n4nECpQFnBFiKkt6N",
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-10-11T11:59:16.988Z"),
        "lat" : -1.2861292178882062,
        "lng" : 36.89101696014404,
        "eventop" : "0800123456",
        "eventtitle" : "test2",
        "eventtime" : ISODate("2016-10-11T11:59:16.988Z"),
        "invited" : "0800123456",
        "hour" : "0",
        "minute" : "1",
        "pmam" : "pm",
        "eventduration" : "60",
        "eventtype" : "4",
        "eventcategory" : "hackathon",
        "eventstatus" : 11
}


{
        "_id" : "LtFB4WMu4xGC7Kyxf",
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-10-11T11:59:16.939Z"),
        "lat" : -1.284970795243023,
        "lng" : 36.89183235168457,
        "primaryowner" : "0800123456",
        "eventtitle" : "test2",
        "eventtime" : ISODate("2016-10-11T11:59:16.939Z"),
        "hour" : "0",
        "minute" : "1",
        "pmam" : "pm",
        "eventduration" : "60",
        "eventtype" : "4",
        "eventcategory" : "hackathon",
        "eventstatus" : 11
}
```

I want to fetch some data from the collections `invites`. This is the data i want to get.

I want to get data(all fields) where `invited field is 0800123456` and `eventtype is 3` and `eventstatus is 11`. I also want to get data where `eventtype is 4` where `eventstatus is 4` and the field `primaryowner` exists.

`db.invites.find({invited:"0720069005",eventtype:"3"},{eventstatus:"11"},{$and: [{eventtype: "4"},{eventstatus:"11"},{primaryowner: { $exists: true }}]}).pretty()`

This is my query.It returns some data but i am not sure whether its correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, I couldnot clearly understand what is the required business scenario, but with the sample data provided I have given an pseudo code and the respective mongodb implementation of that pseudo code.

```
if invited field is "0800123456" 
   if event type is 3 and event status is 11
     select matching documents
or if event type is 4 and event status is 11 and primary owner exists
     select matching documents
```

Mongo DB Query

```
db.collection.find({
  $or: [
    {
      $and: [
        {
          "invited": "0800123456"
        },
        {
          "eventtype": {
            $eq: "3"
          }
        },
        {
          "eventstatus": {
            $eq: 11
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      $and: [
        {
          "eventtype": {
            $eq: "4"
          }
        },
        {
          "eventstatus": {
            $eq: 11
          }
        },
        {
          primaryowner: {
            $exists: true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
})
```

If this is not matching your scenario, then write your own query with the help of this sample code.

Hope it Helps!